# windows server 2003 cannot accept connections

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

I am running a Windows Server 2003 OS and am noticing that no one is able to connect to the machine through Remote Desktop. I have gone through the Terminal Services Configuration to make sure that we had the RDP-Tcp connection enabled and I've checked to see that the server was listening to port 3389. Are there any other options since I've tried to ping into our host server with no results.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have outbound connectivity? Also, what are the specific error messages when you try to connect? Give us a bit more detail and we can probably help a lot more.

Comment: I do have an internet connection that is working. I can access websites with no problem. As far as the error is concerned I get the typical cannot connect to host machine and it gives me some options to check. Such as Remote Server connection being enabled, the computer being turned on, or the computer not being available on the network. Everything was working fine a week ago. I am not sure on what could've changed from then to now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. Apparently I had to remove the remote access/VPN role from and install it again. Except this time to uncheck the box for Basic Firewall. Hope this helps someone out.